# pass multiple clones to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on an ajax form and I have a question about the ability to pass all the clones of a field that have been created to and thru ajax over to php. I can take care of the php stuff just fine, I just need to get the all the variables that the clone produces.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
function GetHtml1() {
    var len = $('.extraAttribute').length;
    var $html = $('.extraAttributeTemplate').clone();
    $html.find('[name=attribute]')[0].name = "attribute" + len;
    return $html.html();
}
```

When someone clicks on the Add Attribute link, this is the clone field produced:

```
<input class="span3" placeholder="Attribute" type="text" id="attribute" name="attribute">
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's the issue, did you try just sending the HTML string to PHP ?

Comment: When someone clicks on add attribute, it expands another field, it will capture the name="attribute" but not the multiple name="attribute" - it will need to be an array or each attribute gets a unique id. Preferably an array tho

Comment: Doing [0] gets you only the first element, are you saying there's multiple elements with the same name, and you'd like an array of the values of all those elements ?

Comment: When you clone the field, you must ensure that certain attributes are unique, such as ID. Also, if you were posting a form, I would recommend that you make the name field into an array: `name="attribute[]"`. However, it seems you are looping through the fields and collating the data yourself before submitting via AJAX.

Comment: yes please. the name="attribute" will need to be an array

Comment: I'm sorry - but if I knew how to do that, then I wouldn't have posted my question :(

Comment: See adeneo's answer, esp. final para.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you were not able to use adeneo's answer. He's one of the very best and brightest on here, and his answer was excellent. However, I suspect you needed a more detailed code example to see how it all fit together. Unfortunately, time is no one's friend. Perhaps if you had also posted a jsFiddle with some sample code, we could have provided a more helpful (detailed) answer. Please keep in mind for next time. We really do desire to help!

Comment: @gibberish - Wow, thank you for the kind words.